# build array from string

Tags: php

I have retrieved the following output from a service.

Output:

> OK: set username OK: set password OK: set server state acquiring-network OK: sign-in OK: get-group-members group contact-list contact 5551000008539 name "Driver 2" state offline group contact-list contact 5551000008540 name "Driver 3" state offline group contact-list contact 5551000008541 name "Driver 4" state offline state connecting client-own-id 5551000008535 client-own-id 0 client-own-id 5551000008535 state disconnecting sign-in denied auth-error client-own-id 0 state offline

How can i extract the data into the user array as before?

how can i explode/implode/preg match or whatever into an array of users. like:

```
$users - Driver 2 => 5551000008539
         Driver 3 => 5551000008540
         Driver 4 => 5551000008541
```

Comment: You probably need to post the exact format of the input string (including newlines) to get a valid answer.

Comment: Perhaps ":" is a separator.  But clarification is needed before I'll try to answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming `$s` contains the output from our service):

```
preg_match_all("/contact-list contact (\\d+) name \"(.*?)\"/", $s, $out, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

And to create an array with names as keys and the numbers as values:

```
$result = array_combine($out[2], $out[1]);
```

Comment: Warning: array_combine() [function.array-combine]: Both parameters should have at least 1 element

Comment: assign `$s = 'OK: set username OK: set password OK: set server state acquiring-network OK: sign-in OK: get-group-members group contact-list contact 5551000008539 name "Driver 2" state offline group contact-list contact 5551000008540 name "Driver 3" state offline group contact-list contact 5551000008541 name "Driver 4" state offline state connecting client-own-id 5551000008535 client-own-id 0 client-own-id 5551000008535 state disconnecting sign-in denied auth-error client-own-id 0 state offline';`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = 'OK: set username OK: set password OK: set server state acquiring-network OK: sign-in OK: get-group-members group contact-list contact 5551000008539 name "Driver 2" state offline group contact-list contact 5551000008540 name "Driver 3" state offline group contact-list contact 5551000008541 name "Driver 4" state offline state connecting client-own-id 5551000008535 client-own-id 0 client-own-id 5551000008535 state disconnecting sign-in denied auth-error client-own-id 0 state offline';
preg_match_all('@contact (\d+) name "(.+?)"@', $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
print_r($matches);
$array = array();
foreach($matches as $match) {
    $array[$match[2]] = $match[1];
}
print_r($array);
```

<strike>Salvaging the data from $matches is left as an exercise.</strike>

Comment: just got 2 empty arrays.. Array ( ) Array ( )